# Как очистить Checkmark в tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, activityindicator

У меня есть tableView. Если я нажимаю на ячейку, то начинается загрузка файла с анимацией `UIActivityIndicator`. После того как загрузка завершена появляется галочка(файл существует) и пользователь может перейти к следующему контроллеру. Нужно чтобы после перехода и возвращения назад все галочки исчезли. Как это сделать?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (indexPath.row == 1){
if (!fileExists) {
        [_spinner startAnimating];
    }
    if (fileExists) {
 cell.accessoryView = nil;
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
 }
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 2){
if (!fileExists1) {
        [_spinner1 startAnimating];
     }

        if (fileExists1) {
            cell.accessoryView = nil;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row == 1) {

if (!fileExists) {
 _spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
 _spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.accessoryView = _spinner;
 tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = _spinner;
 [_spinner startAnimating];

if (fileExists) {
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Например сделать чтоб условие при котором будет ставиться галочка не выполнилось и reload таблицу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следующий код в `cellForRowAtIndexPath` только ставит `checkmark`, но он не очистит `accessoryType` если `checkmark` стоит и он не нужен (такое может быть если ячейка таблицы была использована раньше):

```
BOOL shouldSetCheckmark = ...; // ваша логика решающая должен ли `checkmark` быть показан

if (shouldSetCheckmark) {
 cell.accessoryView = nil;
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Вот этот код уберет `checkmark` если он не нужен:

```
if (shouldSetCheckmark) cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
else cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Comment: Ваш код убирает  `checkmark` если файла не существует.  А мне нужно поставить  `checkmark` после того как файл будет скачан и убрать `checkmark` навсегда если пользователь перешел к следующему контроллеру.

Comment: @user поправил ответ - `shouldSetCheckmark` нужно выставить соответствующе

Comment: Вся проблема в логике. Галочка у меня появляется когда файл найден. То есть я не могу ее скрыть если файл еще существует. Можно ли ставить галочку, когда загрузка будет завершена, а не когда файл существует? Как мне узнать когда загрузка завершилась не проверяя при этом нахождение файла в директории?

Comment: @user ответил на ваш вопрос по загрузке файла тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599924/objective-c-Загрузка-файла/599975#599975