# Objective-C: Загрузка файла

Tags: ios, objective-c, файлы

Я использую этот код чтобы скачать файл.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.mp3"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:false];

NSString *stringURL = @"link";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

и этот чтобы узнать что файл существует

```
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:false];
```

Я хочу узнать когда загрузка этого файла была завершена(не когда файл существует в директории) и создать проверку по типу:

```
if (загрузка файла была завершена) {
//действие
}
```

Как это сделать?

**UPD**

```
if (indexPath.row == 1) {

                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.mp3"];
                BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:false];
                if (!fileExists) {

                         UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                                       alertControllerWithTitle:@"1"
                                                       message:@"1"
                                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
                         UIAlertAction* actionAdd = [UIAlertAction
                                                     actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                                     {
                        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


                        _spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
                        _spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
                        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                        cell.accessoryView = _spinner;
                        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = _spinner;
                        [_spinner startAnimating];

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{     
                        NSString *dataUrl = @"link";
                        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dataUrl];


                        NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                        dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                        if (((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode == 200) {
                        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                        }
                        }];

                        [downloadTask resume];
                         });
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


                        if (fileExists) {
[_spinner2 stopAnimating];
                        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                        [cell setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                        }
                        });
                        });
                        }];

                         UIAlertAction* actionCancel = [UIAlertAction
                                                        actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                                        {
                                                            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                        }];
                         [alert addAction:actionAdd];
                         [alert addAction :actionCancel];
                         alert.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
                         alert.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 3.4, self.view.bounds.size.height / 4.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                         [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                     }
                     if (fileExists) {
                         [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Segue" sender: self];
                     }
                 }
```

Comment: Вы что конкретно хотите проверять? Существует ли запрашиваемый по URL файл?

Comment: dataWithContentsOfURL и writeToFile это синхронные операции. как только контрол флоу прошел эти строчки все уже готово. если предполагаете, что есть возможность ошибки (например нет места на девайсе), то writeToFile возвращает булеан.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Если нажать на ячейку, начнется загрузка . В моем приложение 40 ячеек  и пользователь может нажать на все. В моем случае лучше не использовать `dataWithContentsOfURL`? Нужно использовать `NSURLSessionDataTask`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следующий код должен скачать файл, и когда файл будет скачан сохранить его в блоке по нужному вам адресу:

```
// показать индикатор активности

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
  @"http://...."];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
 downloadTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    // спрятать индикатор активности

    if (location == nil || error != nil) {
        // ваша обработка ошибки  загрузки
        return; 
    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.mp3"];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:location toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] error:nil];
}];

[downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: Я добавил свой код в вопрос в **UPD**. Если я использую такой код, то мой activity indicator не работает. Если добавляю ваш код, происходит тоже самое. Как это исправить?

Comment: @user затрудняюсь ответить; как activity indicator должен быть связан с загрузкой? Я вижу только что по окончанию загрузки вы сохраняете загруженное на диск.

Comment: У activity indicator должна быть анимация во время загрузки файла. Раньше я использовал первый код в вопросе с `dataWithContentsOfURL:url` и анимация работала. Но когда заменил код на `NSURLSessionDataTask` анимация не работает. Как можно сделать анимацию activity indicator во время загрузки файла?

Comment: @user судя по коду проблема в вашем случае в `cell.accessoryView = nil;` который отрабатывает практически сразу после показа индикатора активности

Comment: Убрал. Индикатор работает. Но когда файл уже загрузился анимация индикатора не останавливается

Comment: @user вероятно нужно добавить соответствующую логику по окончанию загрузки файла

Comment: Добавил `if (fileExists) { [_spinner2 stopAnimating];}` не работает, но это проверка существования файла. А как можно сделать проверку окончания загрузки?

Comment: @user добавил к ответу комментарии про индикатор активности